Constructing a Continuous Function Below an Increasing Function
Let $f$ be an increasing function defined on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$. Does there exists a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $g(x)>0$ on $(0,1]$ and
$$g(x)\leq f(x) \ \ \ \   \forall  x\in [0,1]?$$

Can you detail your efforts?

Yes, it exists. Since $f(1)$ is finite, $f$ must be bounded. Let $g$ be defined by $g(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy$ on $[0,1]$. The function $g$ is well-defined because $f$ is increasing and bounded (take for example the upper and lower Riemann sum, they become equal in the limit). Moreover, $g(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy\leq \int_0^xf(x)dy=x f(x)\leq f(x)$ and $g(x)>0$ if $x>0$.

Do you think the result will still be true if $f$ is bounded but not increasing?
